# Efficient way to subset data into data-frames by 2 columns

Tags: r

I have data that looks like follows:

```
> dput(mylist)
    list(structure(c(60.0090409674794, 60.0100409681621, 60.0110409688448, 
    60.0120409695275, 60.0130409702102, 60.0140409708929, 60.0150409715756, 
    60.0160409722583, 60.0170409729409, 60.0180409736236, -0.055, 
    -0.047, -0.034, -0.021, -0.015, -0.013, -0.01, -0.005, -0.003, 
    -0.007, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("", 
    "", "", "i"))), structure(c(257.906176069569, 257.907176070251, 
    257.908176070934, 257.909176071617, 257.910176072299, 257.911176072982, 
    257.912176073665, 257.913176074348, 257.91417607503, 257.915176075713, 
    -0.001, -0.005, -0.013, -0.013, -0.002, 0.012, 0.016, 0.01, 0.004, 
    0.004, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("", 
    "", "", "i"))), structure(c(1057.51772195514, 1057.51872195582, 
    1057.5197219565, 1057.52072195719, 1057.52172195787, 1057.52272195855, 
    1057.52372195924, 1057.52472195992, 1057.5257219606, 1057.52672196128, 
    0.035, 0.03, 0.026, 0.023, 0.013, -0.012, -0.049, -0.079, -0.078, 
    -0.039, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("", "", "", "i"))))
```

My goal would be to subset this data on a few parameters: the freq number which is column 3 in each and the id number which is column 4. So if I was to have 6 unique ID numbers and 6 unique Frequencies, I'd end up with 36 unique data.frames. The most straightforward way would be to use a for loop and if statements like follows

```
for (i in seq_along(mylist){
       if (mylist[[i]][[,3]][1]== 10 && (mylist[[i]][[,4]][1]== 1)
           testdata=cbind(testdata,trials[[i]][,2]

        ...etc

}
```

But this laborious for this task and would require a lot of time.

A note, I'd only need the second column back not the whole data.frame from the list. My guess is that `filter` from the `dplyr` might be the best option but not sure how to implement it for 36 unique frames. Also, I heard bitmasks might be another good way to go.

Comment: Sounds like you want `split`, but there is rarely a need to do this in R. If you're using dplyr, consider `group_by`

Comment: maybe `lapply(mylist, function(x) split(x, x[,3:4]))`

Comment: Is `trials` a separate data set or is it `mylist`?   Will `testdata` have any identifiers from `mylist` (e.g. `freq` and/or `id` ) or is it just a numeric array?  If it has identifiers, could you give a short example?